# FTP script: GET copies several single files but MGET only copies one file?

Tags: unix, batch-file, ftp, dos

I'm having trouble using ftp's **mget** to copy several XML files from the ftp server to out local machine.

In the ftp prompt, I type in

```
ftp> mget A20130918.14*
```

This is what it returns:

```
ftp> mget A20130918.14*
200 Type set to A.
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for A20130918.1100.xml (5174130 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 5572810 bytes received in 8.88Seconds 627.29Kbytes/sec.
227 Entering Passive Mode (X,X,X,X,X,X)
425 Can't open data connection.
Connection closed by remote host.
ftp>
```

It copies the first file [A20130918.1100.xml], it then displays "Entering passive mode" and stays there for a while. Then it displays "425 Can't open data connection" and then finally "Connection closed by remote host.".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you use the ftp client that is called above, do all of these cmds manually and then you issue the `mget File.*` cmd? `Type set to A` makes me think of ASCII mode for FTP, try typing `binary` before you do the `mget`. Ftp clients have an enormous range of special options, bugs etc. So if above doesn't help. Update your question (NOT in a comment), with output from `ftp --version` (or however you can get your ftp version), as well as version of your OS. Finally, to avoid PATH surprises, always call like '/path/2/ftp` Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up **GET**ting the files individually. The **MGET** only copied the first file, and it seems to be a known issue without a straightforward solution.

As always, I was polite and had tons of fun.

Thanks.